# How to get the RAM name?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a question about RAM information - How do you get its name?

So far, from `Win32_PhysicalMemory` and `Win32_PhysicalMemoryArray` classes I was able to get most of the info except the name (display name; eg. CRUCIAL BALLISTIX SPORT LT RED)

The platform I'm coding on is .NET WinForms - C#.

References I looked at

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemoryarray
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-physicalmemory

My question is: **How can I get the RAM name?**

Here's a piece of code I am using to retrieve the RAM name and/or manufacturer.

```cs
ManagementObjectSearcher myRamObject = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory");

foreach(ManagementObject obj in myRamObject.Get())
{
    RAM.NAME = obj["Name"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why do you mean by "name"? "GDDR5"? "Samsung DDR5 16GB"? etc.

Comment: I mean the display name, eg. CRUCIAL BALLISTIX SPORT LT RED. Or at least the manufacturer of it

Comment: If you're looking for `Manufacturer`, then why haven't you retrieved the information for `Manufacturer`?

Comment: Open Powershell, and type the following: `Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root\cimv2 -Query "Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory" | ForEach-Object { $_ | Select-Object -Property BankLabel, Capacity, Manufacturer, MemoryType, PartNumber, Speed }`

Comment: I did try to retrieve Manufacturer too, but it returned a mixed string with numbers. Is it encrypted or something? It seems odd because CPU and GPU name isnt. I don't know how those benchmark programs do it. Do they use some sort of their own API?

Comment: Can you show the actual output of the command that @user9938 posted, on your system?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ofcourse. https://imgur.com/tQYjiFT

Comment: That is a known issue, 859B is assumed to belong to Crucial. Google "RAM Manufacturer 859B" and you'll see. Unfortunately, there is no list of these ID's and who they belong to. I assume developers of the best software that identifies this to just do the grunt work and compile this list themselves.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you! You're right, I did a little research already about this but was hoping for a list of these IDs. I'll post an answer here once when I find atleast some of them "scattered" around.

Comment: The following [list](http://www.softnology.biz/pdf/JEP106AV.pdf) may be helpful. See [here](https://www.jedec.org/document_search?search_api_views_fulltext=jep106) for the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following shows how to find your computer memory information, including the manufacturer.

**Get Computer Manufacturer**: (PowerShell)

Open a `PowerShell` window and type the following:

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace Root\cimv2 -Query "Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory" | ForEach-Object { $_ | Select-Object -Property BankLabel, Capacity, Manufacturer, MemoryType, PartNumber, Speed }
```

**Get Computer Manufacturer**: (cmd)

Open a `cmd` window and type the following:

```
wmic path Win32_PhysicalMemory get BankLabel, Capacity, Manufacturer, MemoryType, PartNumber, Speed
```

---

**C#**:

**Create a class** (name: MemoryInfoWmi)

**MemoryInfoWmi**:

```
public class MemoryInfoWmi
{
    public string BankLabel { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public int MemoryType { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public int Speed { get; set; }
}
```

**GetMemory**:

```
private List<MemoryInfoWmi> GetMemory()
{
    List<MemoryInfoWmi> memoryInfoList = new List<MemoryInfoWmi>();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    using (ManagementObjectSearcher moSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMemory"))
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject mObj in moSearcher.Get())
        {
            if (mObj == null)
                continue;

            MemoryInfoWmi mInfo = new MemoryInfoWmi();
            mInfo.BankLabel = mObj["BankLabel"]?.ToString();

            int capacity = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(mObj["Capacity"]?.ToString(), out capacity))
                mInfo.Capacity = capacity;

            mInfo.Manufacturer = mObj["Manufacturer"]?.ToString();

            int memoryType = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(mObj["MemoryType"]?.ToString(), out memoryType))
                mInfo.MemoryType = memoryType;

            mInfo.PartNumber = mObj["PartNumber"]?.ToString();

            int speed = 0;
            if (Int32.TryParse(mObj["Speed"]?.ToString(), out speed))
                mInfo.Speed = speed;

            //add
            memoryInfoList.Add(mInfo);

            Debug.WriteLine($"Bank Label: {mInfo.BankLabel} Manufacturer: {mInfo.Manufacturer}");
        }
    }

    return memoryInfoList;
}
```

---

Sometimes, the name of the manufacturer shows up as one or more hexadecimal numbers (without spaces).

[image]

If this occurs, one needs to refer to the [Standard Manufacturer's Identification Code (JEP106)](https://www.jedec.org/document_search?search_api_views_fulltext=jep106) publication to find the relevant information. The document name is `JEP106<revision number>` (ex: JEP106BE) - the list is revised periodically.

Values may be in the following format:

**Two hex values**: The first hex value is the number of continuations, and the second hex value is the (1-based) entry/index number. (if there are 5 continuations, that means that the desired value is in the 6th bank/group).

ex: `859B`

**Note**: The value of `859B`, is actually two hexadecimal numbers: `85` and `9B`.

I believe that there may also be a second format that is used, where each continuation is listed using `7F`. The last hex value would be the desired value.

ex: `7F7F7F7F7F9B`

In the document, the data is listed in a series of groups (banks) with values from 1 to 126. A group may have fewer than 126 entries, but not more. In essence, it's a list of a list.

```
Bank/Group #1: Range from 1...126
Bank/Group #2: Range from 1...126
Bank/Group #3: Range from 1...126
          ...
```

When looking at the documentation, you'll notice values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5...`, as well as hex values listed. However, you'll also notice that the hex values don't seem to correspond to the decimal values. `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` in decimal should also be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` in hex. Why are the values different?

According to the documentation, the hexadecimal value uses 7 data bits and 1 parity bit (odd parity).

Let's look at what the 5th entry would look like. The entry numbers use a 1-based index, so one would expect the value to be `5`. However, because of the parity bit the value shows as `85`.

Open the calculator in Windows, and select "Programmer". Then click the word "Hex". Then type "85". You'll notice the following:

```
HEX: 85
DEC: 133
BIN: 1000 0101
```

Notice that bit 8 is "1". If we look at bits 0-7, we have `000 0101`. In the calculator, if we click on "BIN" and enter this number, we'll see the following:

```
HEX: 5
DEC: 5
BIN: 0000 0101
```

As stated earlier, the 8th bit is a check digit. One way of getting bits 0-7, is to replace the 8th bit with a "0", and then read the entire 8 bits. How can we do that?

We need to take advantage of the rules of logic. Let's look at some truth tables.

**Given:** False = 0; True = 1

We create all possible permutations with repetition.

[image]

[image]

How will this work? In C#, we can use `&` for logical `AND` operations. Likewise, `|` is used for logical `OR` operations.

To put this into practice, let's start with a test hex value: `85`.

```
HEX: 85
DEC: 133
BIN: 1000 0101
```

We need to determine what value we can use with a logical `AND` that will change the 8th bit to `0`. The bit order is `[8][7][6][5][4][3][2][1]` (Little Endian)

**To Determine Endianness**: (PowerShell)

```
[System.BitConverter]::IsLittleEndian
```

The following will change the parity bit to 0 when odd parity is used.

**GetValueWithoutParity**:

```
private uint GetValueWithoutParity(uint originalValue)
{
    //values have odd parity
    //if number of 1's is odd, then eighth bit = 0
    //if number of 1's is even, then eighth bit = 1

    //we need to zero out the eighth bit in order to get the actual value
    //ie: in order to get the value of bits 0-7

    uint mask = 0x7F; //01111111

    //logical AND - search "Bitwise operators" for more info
    return originalValue & mask; 
}
```

If one has a value without parity, one can get the value after adding the parity bit by doing the following:

**GetValueWithParity**:

**Note**: The code for this method is from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152125/c-sharp-parity-bits-from-a-binary-number)

```
private uint GetValueWithParity(uint originalValue)
{
    //values have odd parity
    //if number of 1's is odd, then eighth bit = 0
    //if number of 1's is even, then eighth bit = 1

    string binaryVal = Convert.ToString(originalValue, 2);
    byte[] numberAsByte = new byte[] { (byte)originalValue };

    //create new instance and set value
    BitArray bits = new BitArray(numberAsByte);

    int onesCount = 0;
    
    //count number of 1's
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (bits[i])
            onesCount++; //increment
    }

    if (onesCount % 2 == 0)
    {
        //set the left most bit for odd parity
        bits[7] = true; 
    }

    //copy
    bits.CopyTo(numberAsByte, 0);

    return numberAsByte[0];
}
```

---

Now, we're able to decode the hex value into a value without parity. After removing the parity bit for `85`, we've determined the value without parity is `5`. As previously mentioned, the first hex value is the number of continuations, and the second hex value is the (1-based) entry/index number. (if there are 5 continuations, that means that the desired value is in the 6th bank/group).

After decoding the second value, we find the (1-based) index/entry, is `27`

---

Before proceeding, let's create some classes to store our data in. I've decided that I'll store the data as JSON. You could use XML, if you like.

**Download/install NuGet package**: `Newtonsoft.Json`

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**
- In Solution Explorer, right-click your <project name>, select **Manage NuGet Packages...**. Click **Browse**. In search box, type **Newtonsoft.Json**. Click **Install**. If a prompt appears, click **Yes**.

**Create a class**: (name: Manufacturer)

```
public class Manufacturer
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "groupNumber")]
    public int GroupNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "names")]
    public List<String> Names { get; set; } = new List<String>();
}
```

**Create a class**: (name: RootObjectJson)

```
public class RootObjectJson
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "manufacturer")]
    public List<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; } = new List<Manufacturer>();
}
```

**Add the following using statements to your classes**:

- using System;
- using System.Collections.Generic;
- using Newtonsoft.Json;

**ToDo**: Load data into the classes. This [repository](https://github.com/yatekii/jep106) may be useful.

**Note**: When using the code below, it's necessary to align data so that the desired data starts at index 1. A simple way of doing this is to add filler data (data that won't be used) in index 0.

**Example**:

The following represents a data entry in index 0. This data won't be used, but is used to make it seem that our data is using a 1-based index.

```
{
  "manufacturer": [
    {
      "groupNumber": 0,
      "names": [ "None" ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Then given a value (ex: `859B`), one can do something similar to the following to retrieve the desired data.

**Note**: If you don't want to use "filler data" (place unused data in index 0), change the indices in the method below.

**DecodeManufacturer**:

```
private void DecodeManufacturer(string manufacturerVal, RootObjectJson root)
{
    uint groupNumber = 0;
    uint numberOfContinuations = 1;
    uint entryNumber = 1;
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(manufacturerVal))
    {
        if (manufacturerVal.Length > 2)
        {
            uint currentVal = 0;

            //ToDo: ensure each hex value is 2 chars
            //if necessary, pad with a leading '0'
            for (int i = 0; i < manufacturerVal.Length; i+=2)
            {
                //Debug.WriteLine($"i = {i} manufacturerVal.Length: {manufacturerVal.Length}");

                //get decimal value of hex value
                string currentStr = manufacturerVal.Substring(i, 2);
                string currentStrAsHex = String.Format("0x{0}", currentStr);

                //convert to uint
                currentVal = Convert.ToUInt32(currentStrAsHex, 16);

                //Debug.WriteLine($"currentStrAsHex: {currentStrAsHex} currentVal: {currentVal}");

                if (i == 0 && manufacturerVal.Length > 2 && manufacturerVal.Length <= 4)
                {
                    
                    numberOfContinuations = GetValueWithoutParity(currentVal);

                    //set value
                    groupNumber = numberOfContinuations + 1;

                    //Debug.WriteLine($"numberOfContinuations: {numberOfContinuations} groupNumber: {groupNumber}");
                }
                else if (i == 2 && manufacturerVal.Length > 2 && manufacturerVal.Length <= 4)
                {
                    
                    entryNumber = GetValueWithoutParity(currentVal);
                    //Debug.WriteLine("entryNumber: " + entryNumber);

                    Debug.WriteLine($"numberOfContinuations: {numberOfContinuations} groupNumber: {groupNumber} entryNumber: {entryNumber}");

                    //need to convert to int to use as an index for the lists
                    int groupNumberInt = (int)groupNumber;
                    int entryNumberInt = (int)entryNumber;

                    if (groupNumberInt < root.Manufacturers.Count && entryNumber < root.Manufacturers[groupNumberInt].Names.Count)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine($"Manufacturer Name: '{root.Manufacturers[groupNumberInt].Names[entryNumberInt]}' Hex: {GetValueWithParity(entryNumber).ToString("X2")}");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Error: Invalid input.");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**:

- [Bitwise and shift operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators)
- [How to check whether a system is big endian or little endian?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181951/how-to-check-whether-a-system-is-big-endian-or-little-endian)
- [Converting Hex string to Int in C#](https://theburningmonk.com/2010/02/converting-hex-to-int-in-csharp/)
- [Program to find parity](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-parity/)
- [C# Parity Bits from a Binary Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152125/c-sharp-parity-bits-from-a-binary-number)
- [Convert an integer to a binary string with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905188/convert-an-integer-to-a-binary-string-with-leading-zeros)
- [What is the JEDEC JEP-106 Manufacturer ID Code and how does Arm use it?](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ka001301/latest)
- [How to clear the most significant bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790233/how-to-clear-the-most-significant-bit)
- [Convert String to Hex and Hex to String in .NET](http://www.nullskull.com/faq/834/convert-string-to-hex-and-hex-to-string-in-net.aspx)
- [Serializing and Deserializing JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm)
- [Serialization Attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)

Comment: Amazing code, congratulations. A question: in DecodeManufacturer, penultimate DebugWriteLine points (towards end of the line) to GetValueWithParity2 (is this meant to be GetValueWithParity ? or should GetValueWithParity2 be created?). Thank you again for sharing your expertise.

Comment: @Nick: GetValueWithParity2 is an alternate version of GetValueWithParity which I used for  testing. It produces the same output, so I didn't include it. I've removed the reference to it in the code above.